# How to reset `ip a` index to start at `1` and end at `number of devices`

Tags: networking, command-line, server, kernel, ip

The command `ip a` shows list of network ports and also shows an index.

For example, `1` for `lo` and `2` for `enp5s0` here:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
```

How to reset the index? I have **attached a screenshot** of the index missing many numbers in between. That is, it shows 15, (missing 16 to 18), 19, (missing 20 to 86), 87 to 94, (missing 95 to 117), 118, 119. This is caused by creation of virtual devices and deletion of them. Now here how to make `ip a` show the numbers continuously starting from 1 and if there are 10 devices, index should be from 1 to 10?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not really indexes but rather `ip` command specific sequential numbers that get messed up when interfaces are deleted and they shouldn't be relied upon for identifying interfaces ... A way to reset them is to simply **reboot** your system so that the kernel's list of devices are recreated.

You can, however, make them display as you like, if that is important to you, with e.g. something like:

```bash
ip a | awk '$0 ~ "^[0-9]+:" {i++; sub("^[0-9]+:",i":")}1'
```

I did run `ip` through `strace` to try and find the source of these numbers and it appears they are created internally by `ip` with no apparent indication to external source.

A further look at [the source code](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/net/iproute2/) confirms the above assumption and reveals that `ip` pulls device data directly from the kernel and for some reason it appears that deleted devices keep added to the total number of devices but not shown in the output.

[This](http://linux-ip.net/html/tools-ip-address.html) might clearly explain ... **Specifically**: "*Each device is given an sequential number as an identifying number. This is merely a convenience, and should not be used to refer to devices.*".

Comment: +1 A thorough, clear, and clean answer.