# how to reorder output of "ip address"?

Tags: command-line, bash, interface, ip-address

I'd like to know if it's possible to reorder the sequence of interfaces in the output of the cli command:

```
ip address
```

Where is it defined in which order the interfaces are listed?

I have 13 interfaces including bridged interfaces and vlan interfaces.

Their order is arbitrary and I'd like to change that.

I'm using "Network-Manager" and "Advanced Networking Configuration" Tool for configuration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset \`ip a\` index to start at \`1\` and end at \`number of devices\`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1453282/how-to-reset-ip-a-index-to-start-at-1-and-end-at-number-of-devices)

Comment: No, I asked about where the the order of the output of "ip address" is defined and if this can be changed / adjusted. This answer dosn't give any of that information. But popey answered a part of the question. I guess I was hoping to change the order by text-editing some file but now it seems more complex and I guess I will live with it as is.

Comment: `ip a` and `ip address` is the same command ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes from `/proc/net/dev`. For example:

```bash
alan@earth:~$ ip address
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:bf:9c:45:77:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp3s0f0
    inet 192.168.0.104/24 metric 100 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic eno1
       valid_lft 5991sec preferred_lft 5991sec
    inet6 fe80::d2bf:9cff:fe45:7740/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:bf:9c:45:77:41 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp3s0f1
```

```bash
alan@earth:~$ cat /proc/net/dev
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
    lo: 1070507017 9072512    0    0    0     0          0         0 1070507017 9072512    0    0    0     0       0          0
  eno1: 1669873916763 1133028998    0 2042363    0     0          0   8542737 57824815006 320245927    0    0    0     0       0          0
  eno2:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

The Linux kernel itself produces this file in `net/core/net-procfs.c`. See the source [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/core/net-procfs.c#L77). Here's the snippet.

```c
static void dev_seq_printf_stats(struct seq_file *seq, struct net_device *dev)
{
    struct rtnl_link_stats64 temp;
    const struct rtnl_link_stats64 *stats = dev_get_stats(dev, &temp);

    seq_printf(seq, "%6s: %7llu %7llu %4llu %4llu %4llu %5llu %10llu %9llu "
           "%8llu %7llu %4llu %4llu %4llu %5llu %7llu %10llu\n",
           dev->name, stats->rx_bytes, stats->rx_packets,
           stats->rx_errors,
           stats->rx_dropped + stats->rx_missed_errors,
           stats->rx_fifo_errors,
           stats->rx_length_errors + stats->rx_over_errors +
            stats->rx_crc_errors + stats->rx_frame_errors,
           stats->rx_compressed, stats->multicast,
           stats->tx_bytes, stats->tx_packets,
           stats->tx_errors, stats->tx_dropped,
           stats->tx_fifo_errors, stats->collisions,
           stats->tx_carrier_errors +
            stats->tx_aborted_errors +
            stats->tx_window_errors +
            stats->tx_heartbeat_errors,
           stats->tx_compressed);
}
```